# File Creation in Java

Tags: java, file

I want to create a file  whose content should be like the one mentioned below :

```
Start

NAME      COLLEGE        COUNTRY    MOBILE

xyz        college1      India      1234567890

abc        college2       Germany    4561237890

End
```

In the above file, the column names are fixed only the values of each row will change. Number of rows are not defined. I tried this using String Template in java, with the following sample.st

```
Start

NAME COLLEGE COUNTRY MOBILE

$name$ $college$ $country$ $mobile$

End
```

Where the place holder values will be replaced by the actual vales . But I am not sure with this appraoch can I have multiple rows .

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the template for each row ? Use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the header and then iterate throught the rows, generate a string via the template and append to the `StringBuilder`.

e.g. in pseudo-ish code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("START\n");
sb.append(....)
foreach(Row r : rows) {
   sb.append(template);
}
sb.append("END\n");
```

Failing that, check out templating libraries such as [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, why not? Just when you read the file make sure you skip the header and the start&end and then read the file line by line.

Also consider using some separators, for example ";" unless you want to read it by something like sed/awk - it's much more comfortable that way when you read it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Formatter` and `Scanner` class:

**File Creation**

```
Formatter f=new Formatter("data.txt");
    f.format("%s%n","START");
    f.format("%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s%n","NAME","COLLEGE","COUNTRY","MOBILE");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
     f.format("%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d%n",i,i,i,i);  // Apply your logic for input over here
    }
    f.format("%s%n","END");
    f.close();
```

**File Reading**

```
    Scanner s=new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
    while(s.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(s.nextLine());   
    }
    s.close();
    }
```